# Can my query with multiple LIKE statements and REGEXP be more efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I'm constructing a dynamic query to select dropped domain names from my database. At the moment there are a dozen rows but I'm going to get data soon which will have records of up to 500,000 rows.

The schema is just one table containing 4 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `DroppedDomains` (
  `domainID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DomainName` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `DropDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `TLD` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`domainID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I did not create the schema, this is the live database schema. Here's sample data:

[image]

I've constructed probably the most complex type of query below. The criteria is as follows:

SELECT any number of domains which

> 1. Start with the word 'starts'
> 2. End with the word 'ends'
> 3. Contain the word 'containsThis' anywhere in the domain name
> 4. Contain the word 'ContainsThisToo' anywhere in the domain name
> 5. Include at least one digit
> 6. The domain name must be at least 49 characters. Multibytes need to count
>      as one character( I used CHAR_LENGTH
>      ).
> 7. The domain name must be at least under 65 characters.
> 8. The TLD must be 'org'
> 9. The DropDate needs to be later than `2009-11-01`

Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
DroppedDomains

WHERE

1=1

AND DomainName LIKE 'starts%ends'
AND DomainName LIKE '%containsThis%'
AND DomainName LIKE '%containsThisToo%'
AND DomainName LIKE '%-%'
AND DomainName REGEXP '[0-9]'
AND CHAR_LENGTH(DomainName) > 49
AND CHAR_LENGTH(DomainName) < 65
AND TLD = 'org'
AND DropDate > '2009-11-01'
```

Here are my questions

1. Would it extremely benefit the performance considering I'll have half a million rows, if I made the `TLD` column its own table and just make the `TLD` column a foreign key to that? There will only be 5 TLDs ( com, net, org, info, biz ). I realize there are more TLDs in the real world, but this application will only have 5. The user cannot specify their own TLD.
2. I know that `REGEXP` and 500,000 rows is probably a recipe for disaster. Is there anyway I can avoid the `REGEXP`?
3. Are there any other optimizations to the query I can do? Like merge `LIKE`s or use other functions such as maybe `INSTR`? And should I implement any specific sort of caching mechanism?

Comment: Note: I know that I shouldn't use `SELECT.*` because further columns may be added in the future and performance may be negated by selecting unnecessary columns. It's for demonstration/testing purposes only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a LIKE pattern that starts with a constant prefix and you have an index on that field, then the index can be used to find the rows starting with the prefix very quickly. Luckily you have exactly this situation here:

```
AND DomainName LIKE 'starts%ends'
```

If only a few of the values start with `starts` then these rows will be found very quickly and the other expressions will only be tested for these rows. You can check that the index is used by running `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: So does that mean my query is pretty much almost as optimized as can be?

Comment: @meder: If you have the correct indexes, then yes. You may also want to consider a multi-column index here since you have multiple fields that you are testing. Note: the order of the columns in a multi-column index is important. You may need to experiment to see which index works best. It depends a lot on the distribution of your data. For example you might find that an index on `(TLD, DomainName)` works well for some queries, but `(TLD, DropDate)` works better for others. Try a few different indexes and see which is best.

Comment: By indexes do you mean internally stored indexes, or am I supposed to actually somehow generate some "cached" state of the database? I feel stupid for asking, did I not learn a critical part of sql/dbs?

Comment: On second thought I think it's coming back to me, but I haven't been using indexes all this time.

Comment: @meder: Yes, I'd say that understanding indexes is a critical part of using a RDBMS. You can refer to [How MySQL uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) which also mentions the LIKE optimization that I wrote in my answer. I'd also suggest getting a good MySQL book as the MySQL docs are sometimes pretty heavy reading and not so good as a tutorial. PS: To create an index you can use the [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should plan the indexes to be created according to the queries you plan to use.

- if you'll have queries that filter
  only by DropDate, then an index on
  the DropDate will be useful.
- if you'll have queries that group by
  TLD, then an index on TLD will be
  useful.
- if you'll have queries that search
  only by length of DomainName, then
  you may consider adding a field DomainNameLength that
  has exactly that (and an index on this) so
  the length is not calculated every
  time you run the query.
- if you'll have queries that search (filter) by two fields (e.g. TLD and DropDate), then you probably need a 2-column index on these fields.
- etc...

If your only query you'll use is the complex one you mention, then Mark's advice (about an index on DomainName) is best.

Regarding question 1 about `TLD` field:

If you are really going to have only a small number (like 5) of options for this and you are not planning to use all available tlds, you could use the [`ENUM` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).

```
CREATE TABLE(
   ....
   tld ENUM('com', 'net', 'org', 'info', 'biz')
)
```

Comment: Oh, I'll definitely have different queries going on, so it looks like I need to throw indexes on a bunch of the columns: http://i.imgur.com/Z9aSb.jpg . I have the data now so I'll play around and try to compare query speed with and without indexes - thanks for the tips.